# Incorrect redirect when removing language subdomain from a Stack Overflow URL

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, international-sites

I arrived at this question from Google: [CakePHP no me carca los estilos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/172117/cakephp-no-me-carca-los-estilos) (`https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/172117/cakephp-no-me-carca-los-estilos`)

I noticed it was in Spanish, so I attempted to remove `es` from the URL hoping for an English version. The URL becomes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172117/cakephp-no-me-carca-los-estilos (`https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/172117/cakephp-no-me-carca-los-estilos`)

I expected an English version, but instead was redirected to a completely different question: [.Net (dotNet) wrappers for OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85569/net-dotnet-wrappers-for-opencv/172117#172117) (`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85569/net-dotnet-wrappers-for-opencv/172117#172117`)

I haven't tested this elsewhere.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Adding the language subdomain does not merely change the language of Stack Overflow to another. Stack Overflow is a completely separate site and community from Stack Overflow in Spanish. One is not a translated version of the other. It is a completely different database of questions and answers.

Removing the subdomain would not ever result in the same question. What happens is that the Id for a question on one site is the Id for an answer to a different question on the other. It performs a redirect to correct the question Id that is the parent of the answer with that Id number, keeping the answer Id at the end to highlight it on the page. If it had corresponded to another question, it would have merely corrected the slug in the URL.

Comment: I understand that in this instance I was incorrectly assuming that stack overflow would perform a translation. I'm used to various services that do this and that's my mistake. I also assumed the ID being used was the slug, when infact it's the `172117` that's the ID. Thank you :D